# When is it necessary to use `rerender` with the React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

In times past, my colleagues and I would typically write React Testing Library (RTL) tests for the main parent components, which often have many nested child components.  That testing made sense and worked well.  Btw the child components in question are very much dedicated to that parent component and not of the reusable variety.

But now we're trying to write RTL tests for every single component.  Today I was trying to build tests for an `Alerts` component, which is the parent of an `Alert` component and about 4 levels down from the top-level component.  Here's some sample code in my test file:

```
function renderDom(component, store) {
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>),
    store,
  };
}

let store = configureStore(_initialState);
const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
const { queryByTestId, queryByText, debug } = renderDom(
  <Alerts question={store.getState().pageBuilder.userForm.steps[0].tasks[0].questions[1]} />,
  store
);
```

I then started writing the typical RTL code to get the `Alerts` component to do its thing.  One of these was to click on a button which would trigger an `ADD_ALERT` action.  I stepped through all of the code and the Redux reducer was apparently working correctly with a new alert, as I intended, yet back in the `Alerts` component, `question.alerts` remained `null` whereas in the production code it was definitely being updated properly with a new alert.

I spoke with a colleague and he said that for this type of test, I would need to artificially rerender the component like this:

```
rerender(<Provider store={store}><Alerts question={store.getState().pageBuilder.userForm.steps[0].tasks[0].questions[1]} /></Provider>);
```

I tried this and it appears to be a solution.  I don't fully understand why I have to do this and thought I'd reach out to the community to see if there was a way I could avoid using `rerender`.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to be certain without seeing more of your code, but my typical approach with RTL is to take the `fireEvent` call that simulates clicking the button and wrap it in an [act](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#act) call. This should cause React to finish processing any events from your event, update states, rerender, etc.

Alternatively, if you know that a particular DOM change should occur as a result of firing the event, you can use `waitFor`. An example from the [React Testing Library intro](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro):

```
  render(<Fetch url="/greeting" />)

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Load Greeting'))

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('alert'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the motivation behind the `rerender` API is to allow you to use a different set of `props`.

I agree that `rerender` is an akward API to achieve this goal. Akward because "re-rendering" is an implementation concept, and it doesn't fit the spirit of React Testing Library that encourage to not rely on implementation details. I always scratch my head when I have to use it.

On the other hand, it's pretty difficult to write a test that simulates `props` changes. You could write a stateful wrapper component with a button, and make sure that each click on the button update `props`. That's a big hassle I would say. So `rerender` might be a reasonable design choice. Personally, I would prefer `updateProps` API that accepts an object with `Partial<OriginalProps>` interface.

Comment: Nice point about it being awkward. I wonder why they didn't use the same design for `rerender` with components as they did with `rerender` with hooks?
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender-1